# Why can't I replace IEnumerable<T> by a generic type variable in extension method?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I am trying to make an extension method more generic to avoid redundancy ([Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24953540/1016343) of some real code, the code below is just to demonstrate the issue - I had the idea to make the method available for `IQueryable<T>` as well).

The following works fine:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> MySelect1<T, V>(this IEnumerable<T> query, Func<T, V> f)
    {
        // do something, then return IEnumerable<T>
        var result=query.AsEnumerable<T>();
        return result;
    }
    public static IQueryable<T> MySelect1<T, V>(this IQueryable<T> query, Func<T, V> f)
    {
        // do something, then return IQueryable<T>
        var result = query.AsQueryable<T>();
        return result;
    }
}
```

I can use it in LinqPad like (when connected with the [Northwind sample database](https://parallelcodes.com/install-and-attach-northwind-database-in-sql-management-studio/)):

```
var myQuery=(from x in Customers select x);
myQuery.AsEnumerable().MySelect1(d => d.CustomerID).Dump();
myQuery.AsQueryable().MySelect1(d => d.CustomerID).Dump();
```

Now I wanted to get rid of the duplicate implementation of MySelect1, so I refactored it as:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static E MySelect2<E, T, V>(this E query, Func<T, V> f)
    where E : System.Linq.IQueryable<T>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>
    {
        return (E)query.Select(f);
    }
}
```

This compiles too, but I cannot use MySelect2 the same way as I did above, consider the following:

```
// CS0411 The type arguments for method 'Extensions.MySelect2<E, T, V>(E, Func<T, V>)' 
// cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
myQuery.AsEnumerable().MySelect2(d => d.CustomerID).Dump(); 
myQuery.AsQueryable().MySelect2(d => d.CustomerID).Dump();
```

Ok, doing what the error asks for works for this code line:

```
myQuery.AsQueryable()
       .MySelect2<IQueryable<Customers>, Customers, String>(d => d.CustomerID).Dump();
```

but not for that one:

```
myQuery.AsEnumerable<Customers>()
       .MySelect2<IEnumerable<Customers>, Customers, String>(d => d.CustomerID).Dump();
```

Here, I am getting

> CS0311 The type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LINQPad.User.Customers>' cannot be used as type parameter 'E' in the generic type or method 'Extensions.MySelect2<E, T, V>(E, Func<T, V>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<LINQPad.User.Customers>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<LINQPad.User.Customers>'.

Why? And how can it be fixed? Please help.

Comment: "`where E : System.Linq.IQueryable<T>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>`" isn´t the second constraint redundant as an `IQueryable<T>` **is** an `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere - you are right that a queryable object is also enumerable. But I tried to remove the `IQueryable<T>` and in this case, the first statement `myQuery.AsQueryable().MySelect2(...)` was throwing a runtime error (Unable to cast object...).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why?

For exactly the reason stated in the error message: you're trying to use `IEnumerable<Customers>` as the type argument for `E`, but `E` has this constraint:

```
where E : System.Linq.IQueryable<T>
```

> And how can it be fixed?

It can't, assuming I understand what you're trying to achieve.

There's a fundamental problem with the "simplification" you're trying to achieve: you don't actually have full duplication in your original `MySelect1` methods. The first calls `AsEnumerable()` and the second calls `AsQueryable()`. You're trying to replace those with a cast, and that's just not going to work.

There's a further problem, even with your original methods: you're accepting `Func<T, V> f` as a parameter for your queryable-based method, which means any time you call `Select` or similar and passing in `f`, you'll be calling `Enumerable.Select` instead of `Queryable.Select`. To really use `IQueryable<>` properly, you should accept `Expression<Func<T, V>> f` instead. At that point, you won't need to call `AsQueryable` anyway.

Your two methods "should" take radically different paths based on whether you're using LINQ to Objects or a different LINQ provider (e.g. LINQ to SQL), and that can't be hidden as a pure implementation detail without significant changes that would probably make it less useful than you want anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the detailled answer. I have a question: You wrote "E has this constraint `where E: System.Linq.IQueryable<T>`". I have actually two constraints separated by comma - it has also `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` applied to it. As per my understanding, if you have two constraints, then it can be either the first or the second - i.e. **either** `IQueryable<T>` **or** `IEnumerable<T>`, which was the idea behind it. Am I right?

Comment: @Matt: No, you're not. If there are multiple constraints, the type argument must satisfy *all* of them.

Comment: Regarding `.AsQueryable()` and `.AsEnumerable()` - this is just for demo purpose to make sure we have a queryable or an enumerable object. What I also noticed, if I completely remove the constaint from MySelect2, it doesn't even work with the queryable code line any more - because `.Select` is not known any more (CS1929 'E' does not contain a definition for 'Select' ...)

Comment: @Matt: Well yes, that would fail. But importantly, you'd want to call two different methods based on whether it's *actually* a queryable or not - Enumerable.Select and Queryable.Select are completely different methods with different parameter types. If you remove the `IQueryable<T>` constraint but keep the `IEnumerable<T>` constraint you'll be able to compile, but that would basically be using LINQ to Objects for everything, which isn't a good idea - you want as much work as possible to happen in the database.

Comment: @Matt: Fundamentally it's hard to tell what's just "for demo purposes" and what's in your real code, partly as you haven't explained what the real code is for - why you need these extension methods at all. Adding some clarity to the question would help.

Comment: I agree, and I have added a link to an answer I gave a couple of time ago in StackOverflow. The idea was to make it available for both IQueryable and IEnumerable, but it seems that overloading the method is still the best way to do that.